# How do I start an IBM MQ channel in Java?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

So my Java process communicates with a remote queue. What happens is at the end of every day, the sender channel on the receiving end is in a stopped state. Is there a way to start up that channel in Java, before accessing the remote queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and found an answer. I have to define a trigger on the transmission queue that will start the sender channel.

Here are some links that helped:

[Google Search](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=ibm+mq+channel+trigger&aq=f&aqi=&fp=35e5f905b5e4329b)
[Google MQ User Group](http://groups.google.com/group/ibm.software.websphere.mq.programming/browse_thread/thread/d676c181b4db5e12?fwc=1&pli=1)
[IBM MQSeries Tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0202_balani/balani.html)